# relation between "疏" and "上命" (clarifying meaning in a sentence)

Tags: translation, classical-chinese

I have a couple of problems concerning this sentence:

庚辰，具疏投進，上命校書館印布正文，其後玉堂權尚游、尹趾仁請下兩南，竝注疏印進，學士大夫皆印藏而賞。

1. How does 上命 relate to the previous clause (具疏投進)?
2. I am not sure how to understand "尚游" in this context.
3. In the sentence @請下兩南@ the word “两” refers to 玉堂權 and 尹趾仁 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by google, the text in question is korean related, so, my answer would be less accurate

https://blog.daum.net/choiss2166/7573427

> 始克成書・名曰禮記類編・庚辰・具疏投進・上命校書館印布正文

[崔錫萬・字汝時] written a book, named “禮記類編”. on the day “庚辰”, he submitted a notice (疏 —> 奏疏, i’m not sure the proper english translation) to the emperor (具疏投進). [after reading], the emperor ordered (上命) the institution (校書館) to print and distribute (印布) the corrected text (正文)

> 玉堂

“玉堂” is the name of korean government institutions, in ancient time

[https://baike.baidu.hk/item/弘文館/50841219](https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E5%BC%98%E6%96%87%E9%A4%A8/50841219)

therefore, “尙游” is the name (most likely 字, or 名) of an official (mr 權) in such institution.

> In the sentence @請下兩南@ the word “两” refers to 玉堂權 and 尹趾仁

i don’t think so, my best guess is some entities’ name started with “南”

Comment: Thanks this clarifies a lot, I completely messed up this sentence :).